# How to fix "AttributeError: 'Calc' object has no attribute 'input_value'" in the following code?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am making GUI scientific calculator with Tkinter. And I am always getting attribute error for Calc object

I have tried following code, but with no success:

```
class Calc():
    def ___init___(self):
        self.total=0
        self.current = ""
        self.input_value = True
        self.check_sum = False
        self.op = ""
        self.result = False

    def NumberEnter(self, num):
        self.result = False
        firstnum = txtDisplay.get()
        secondnum = str(num)
        if self.input_value:
           self.current = secondnum
           self.input_value = False
        else:
            if secondnum == ".":
                if secondnum in firstnum:
                    return
            self.current=firstnum + secondnum
        self.display(self.current)

    def display(self,value):
        txtDisplay.delete(0,END)
        txtDisplay.insert(0,value)

added_value = Calc()
```

and function call:

```
btn[i]["command"]=lambda x=numberpad [i]: added_value.NumberEnter(x)
```

I am always getting the following message:

```
if self.input_value:
AttributeError: 'Calc' object has no attribute 'input_value'
```

And I should get numbers [0-9] in my calculator window.
Please can somebody help me with this? Thank you.

Comment: are you sure that your indentations in the code are correct?

Comment: They should be,why?

Comment: Basics of python is code indentation. If we don't follow the basic rules of a programming language, we might as well build sand castles on a windy day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You used 3 underscores instead of 2 in your `__init__`.

Change:

```
class Calc():
    def ___init___(self):
       ...
```

To:

```
class Calc:
    def __init__(self): #2 underscores on each side
```

Answer (score 0):

your display function is not indented properly you might want to check that out.